# In my Blazor server side app, when I select a menu in the side bar the menue is highlighted with a blue border. How can I disable this?

Tags: css, browser, menu, blazor-server-side

In my Blazor server side app, when I select a menu in the side bar a blue border is shown. I haven't defined this in the css or elsewhere. How can I disable this? Is it coming from the browser? I am using firefox.

```
<NavLink href="logs" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
  <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Error Log
</NavLink>

<NavLink href="connect2" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
  <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Connect
</NavLink>

<NavLink @onclick="()=>expandSubNav = !expandSubNav">
  <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Windows WMI
</NavLink
```

[image]

Comment: Have you used your browsers devtools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being applied?